# How to Fix "The program is blocked by Group policy " issue while executing the .exe in Azure Automation (Powershell runbook)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a runbook which uses C# dll as module. This C# code starts the process(.exe) internally. which is not working in Azure automation(powershell runbook). can someone please help me with this.

I tried to delete the HKCU:\ items present in Microsoft folder but couldn't succeed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Azure Automation Hybrid Runbook worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) to

"To overcome the Azure Automation sandbox limitation - the common scenarios include executing long-running operations beyond three-hour limit for cloud jobs, performing resource-intensive automation operations, interacting with local services running on-premises or in hybrid environment, run scripts that require elevated permissions"